# Tracking user source and clickstream in Java / Spring

Tags: java, spring, google-analytics, analytics, web-traffic

I am looking for a way to track users including:
- source: where did they come from . Similar to Google analytics: source, medium, campaign, keywords
- clickstream - which pages they visited

I want to answer questions like, when a user registered, where did he come from (search engine, Adwords etc.)

We are using google analytics but they do not provide this info.

I used in the past clickstream from opensymphony but that project has died. Any ideas for an existing package? Preferably for java spring?

Answer (score 0):

Even though the Opensymphony project may not be maintained any longer, it may still be the best fit for your needs.  What are your reasons for discontinuing it's use?

As it is open source, what about forking it for your own needs?

Comment: FYI it seems that the clickstreams project was migrated to Google Code https://code.google.com/p/clickstream/

Comment: I have used Opensymphony before. Some of the search engines etc. need to be updated.